# How to show insecure content in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension

In short , I'm developing a google chrome extension , when I add any url starting with `http://` to source attribute to an `iframe`, I get  a message like :

> [blocked] The page at 'https://www.facebook.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://youtu.be/m0QxDjRdIq4':
>   this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

and I don't see the content in the iframe !
so how can I overcome this ?

what I want to achieve is that : I hide facebook adds , and in its place I added an `iframe` instead, I detect when the mouse is hovering over a link contained in a post, then I want to show the link's content in an iframe.

What are my possible alternatives? I don't need to enable showing insecure content in chrome because it is a chrome extension that I will publish!

Comment: For the record, YT works just fine over HTTPS.

Comment: What makes you think this is possible?

Comment: @Xan I'm asking if it is possible , or for an answer that achieves my goal- to show url content in an iframe , or something else if possible

Comment: To make it possible to help you, please describe what you're trying to achieve in more detail. There can be a simpler solution for a less generic problem.

Comment: @Xan I edited the post..you can understand better now

Comment: So basically you want to make previews available on hover. Or you really need an iframe you can interact with? Of _any_ link?

Comment: yes, this what I want, in an iframe I think it's the best way(if I can) else, I can accept any other good idea; my purpose is to make previews available on hover as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the security limit is strict, so we need a way to work around that.

What if you could load the page using other means than an `<iframe>` and insert it into the page afterwards? There are multiple ways to do that, ranging from more practical to less realistic.

1. You can use the Chrome [`captureVisibleTab` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab) to generate a screenshot of a website as an image, exactly what you need. It sounds like you need a visible tab to use this API, but you can actually specify any Chrome window as a target and you can create Chrome windows [unfocused and hidden behind the edge of the screen](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create).
2. If `captureVisibleTab` provides trouble in step 2, there is also [`pageCapture` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture) to get an entire page as a single content object.
3. You can also use a server to create screenshots. Serve a simple application over HTTPS that uses [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to create a screenshot. An advantage of this approach is your server is likely to be much faster at screenshot generation. The disadvantage is you need to pay for the server.
4. You could also use xhr in your extension background process (which is not limited by the security limitation) to get the HTML. This wouldn't get any resources, but that could be a beneficial thing if you want a very quick if inaccurate screenshot. Just load HTML, parse and detect links to stylesheets, download them and inject those stylesheets into the HTML as `<style>` tags.
   The resulting HTML can be injected to the `<iframe>` manually. You could even inject scripts and images this way, but that would be harder and less useful, since you need a quick screenshot of how the page looks like.

I think using built-in Chrome functionality for screenshots is the best bet, if only you can make the user experience good enough.

Comment: thank you very much @Denis , if I  use pageCapture API , I need to give it tabId , so I have to open a window or a tab to a specific url , then to capture its page , am I right ? and as I read I can' open a hidden window !

Comment: My first option describes a better api than pageCapture, the captureVisibleTab API. The same option also explains how to open a window nicely.

Comment: yes you're right, but the issue now is how to create a hidden window to be able to capture its page! , I can make it unfocused , but not hidden !

Comment: I make a new window behind the edge of the screen , it is hidden from the screen , but I can see it in taskbar

Comment: Well, at the moment this is the best you can do using Chrome's API. But you should close that window quickly after you got a screenshot, so it won't be there for long, right?

Comment: yes,you're right, I can accept that , but here's another problem :                        chrome.windows.create({url: "http://www.google.com",focused:false,left:10000,top:10000},function(window) {

 chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(window.id,function(data) {
 
       document.getElementById('img').src = data;
 });
 chrome.windows.remove(window.id,function(){});
       
  });
  });  // the problem in CaptureVisibleTab ,when I set the first parameter to window.id it doesn't work , when I set it null , it works and capture the current window,I'm afraid that I can't capture not current window

Comment: @KaramNajjar, StackOverflow is for concrete questions and answers. Please avoid discussing your problems unrelated to the original question deeper. That said, read the docs and see what you are doing wrong. Make sure you have added the <all_urls> permission, for example.

Comment: ok I will search for that , although I've already searched a lot,and <all_urls> permission exists, anyway my last question if you're certain that I can capture any window by captureVisibleTab and that's all , thank you

Answer (score 2):

First and stupid way: change `http` in link on `https`. But youtube and I think many other sites don't allow to show their content in iframes. try it and you get `Refused to display 'link' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Second and at least stupid way: remove protocol from link, like `//youtu.be/m0QxDjRdIq4` and you get protocol, that on this page. But a situation similar to the previous.

Third way for youtube only: you can generate iframe with `src` like `//www.youtube.com/embed/m0QxDjRdIq4` and user can see the video.

Fourth way, not for all sites: use site API's - not a best solution, but like a option.

Fifth way, but impossible (I think): try to get page's content with javascript and regenerate it in way, that you need.

Sixth way, needs powerfull server: create an service on your server, which will download pages and resend it to users. One problem - linear dependence server's power of requests.

Seventh way, I forgot that it's extension: you can open link in another tab/window, get it content, close tab/window and show content in tab that you need.

Eigth way, the best, I think: use YAHOO yql like this:

```
$.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select"  
          +"* from html where url='youtube.com/watch?v=m0QxDjRdIq4'"  
          +"&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?"  
  , function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {  
    // process data  
  }  
}
```

[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/mpr9j7b2/)

Comment: I've tried you last way in answer , I modified it a little bit , when I use alert(data);  it returns object , what does it has ? html source ? and how to get it  @ostapische

Comment: @KaramNajjar you get page content in JSON format, try out demo on jsfiddle, I'm update answer.

Comment: so by getting page's content in JSON , can I display the page it self ? if yes , how ?

Comment: Generate tags from `data.query.results.body` and append it to where you want.

Comment: I tried to append it to an iframe src , it didn't work ! , can you show me jsfiddle please ?

Comment: @KaramNajjar you must generate all tags like this http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/mpr9j7b2/1/ and append it to some element.